# linker warning: 'WJLibrary has an install name beginning with "/", but it is not from the specified SDK'

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

My build is working, but the linker is giving this warning. I have no idea why, what it means, or what corrective action I am supposed to take. Can anyone explain any portion of the above?

```
Ld /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.build/Release-iphoneos/FreeUnitConverter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FreeUnitConverter normal armv7
cd /Users/william/Documents/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -LWJLibrary -LWJLibrary/Ads -LWJLibrary/build -LWJLibrary/Classes -LWJLibrary/Generic -LWJLibrary/WJLibrary-macOS -LWJLibrary/WJLibraryFramework -LWJLibrary/WJLibraryFrameworkIOS -LWJLibrary/WJLibraryIOS -LWJLibrary/WJLibraryResources.bundle -LWJLibrary/build/Release-iphoneos -LWJLibrary/Classes/App\ Store -LWJLibrary/Classes/C -LWJLibrary/Classes/Categories -LWJLibrary/Classes/Debug -LWJLibrary/Classes/Game\ Center -LWJLibrary/Classes/Geometry -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics -LWJLibrary/Classes/Misc -LWJLibrary/Classes/Settings -LWJLibrary/WJLibraryResources.bundle/Licenses -LWJLibrary/Classes/Categories/NSCategories -LWJLibrary/Classes/Categories/UICategories -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJOrientedGradient -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJPartitions -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView -LWJLibrary/Classes/Settings/Settings\ Cells -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView/UILabelTest -LWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView/UILabelTest/UILabelTest -F/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -FWJLibrary -FWJLibrary/Ads -FWJLibrary/build -FWJLibrary/Classes -FWJLibrary/Generic -FWJLibrary/WJLibrary-macOS -FWJLibrary/WJLibraryFramework -FWJLibrary/WJLibraryFrameworkIOS -FWJLibrary/WJLibraryIOS -FWJLibrary/WJLibraryResources.bundle -FWJLibrary/build/Release-iphoneos -FWJLibrary/Classes/App\ Store -FWJLibrary/Classes/C -FWJLibrary/Classes/Categories -FWJLibrary/Classes/Debug -FWJLibrary/Classes/Game\ Center -FWJLibrary/Classes/Geometry -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics -FWJLibrary/Classes/Misc -FWJLibrary/Classes/Settings -FWJLibrary/WJLibraryResources.bundle/Licenses -FWJLibrary/Classes/Categories/NSCategories -FWJLibrary/Classes/Categories/UICategories -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJOrientedGradient -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJPartitions -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView -FWJLibrary/Classes/Settings/Settings\ Cells -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView/UILabelTest -FWJLibrary/Classes/Graphics/WJView/UILabelTest/UILabelTest -filelist /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.build/Release-iphoneos/FreeUnitConverter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FreeUnitConverter.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.build/Release-iphoneos/FreeUnitConverter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FreeUnitConverter_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Users/william/Applications/FreeUnitConverter.app/FreeUnitConverter -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -framework Accelerate -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework WJLibraryIOS -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.build/Release-iphoneos/FreeUnitConverter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FreeUnitConverter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-bgozykycmwegcwaobycglqsxfprk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FreeUnitConverter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.build/Release-iphoneos/FreeUnitConverter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FreeUnitConverter

ld: warning: WJLibrary/build/Release-iphoneos/WJLibraryIOS.framework/WJLibraryIOS has install name beginning with "/" but it is not from the specified SDK
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, what I needed to do was:

```
 DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE = @rpath
```

in the build settings. And this warning becomes a failure when you submit the app.